# Airflow not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python, sql, type-conversion, airflow

I am developing a dag for airflow which send an array of hashes as json parameter to a sql function.

I used an internal developed function `exec_query` which use cursor to execute query and I just need to pass the sql and the parameters to it.

Here is how I initiate an array of hashes

```
json_array = []
for id, name in whitelist_apps.items():
    app_id = {
       'id': id,
       'name': name,
    }
    json_array.append(app_id))
```

and then call my exec_query as

```
exec_query(
    query='SELECT some_function(%s::JSON)',
    args=(str(json_array)),
)
```

and this is my sql function naming

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION some_function(p_values JSON) RETURNS TEXT
```

the error I get when I run the dag is `TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting`

Why `str()` is not working as expected here? How can I solve the issue?

## Answer

Instead of using `str` I needed to use `json_dumps`. It cast the json to string. The exact change is `args=(json.dumps(json_array),)`

Comment: Could you provide how `exec_query` is defined?

Comment: @PhilippJohannis Yes its `def exec_query(**kwargs)` and it get args as `kwargs["args"]`

Comment: I was more asking for the code - it's hard to debug if you don't know the code.